# Array Pointer not accessible from interrupt

Tags: c, arrays, embedded, stm32

I defined a set of global pointers to do some precomputing of arrays that I need to  access in an interrupt:

```
uint8_t *spiTxBuffers;
```

In my main() I then reserve the space and write some stuff to the arrays:

```
// reserve space for arrays
spiTxBuffers = (uint8_t *) calloc(max_serial*buffer_size, sizeof(uint8_t));


//     precomputing arrays
uint8_t switching_config[number_cells];
for (int i=0; i <= max_serial; i++) {
    decide_config(i, switching_config, number_cells);
    fill_buffer(switching_config, spiTxBuffers + i * buffer_size, number_cells);
}
```

After this checking with the debugger the arrays seemed to be filled correctly.

Now when I access the spiTxBuffers from my interrupt, the array seems to be filled with garbage, random values that change with each interrupt trigger.

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if (htim->Instance==TIM2) //check if the interrupt comes from TIM2
    {
        uint8_t *pResult;
        pResult = (uint8_t *) calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(uint8_t));
        // bunch of code...
        number_of_serial = round(sinus / avg_voltage);
        // make sure were not assuming more serial then we have
        pResult = spiTxBuffers + (number_of_serial*buffer_size);
        //spi transmit...
  }
}
```

When I define and compute the array inside of the interrupt everything works fine, but I want to only compute that array once. Any ideas how the array can be messed up when using it in the interrupt? The code is running on a STM32F4 in C.

Edit:
Running a test access in my normale while loop yields the same result:

```
test = spiTxBuffers[2];
```

test has different values each cycle.
Disabling the interrupt completely doesnt change that effect.

Disabling the DMA ADC fixes the issue, I believe the array for the ADC target was too small.

Comment: Could the interrupt be running in a different memory space (segment)? You can check the array in your `main()` after the interrupt. If it is OK then there is a memory segment problem.

Comment: calloc in the interrupt routine - it is one of the worst mistakes made by the "big computer" programmers when they try to do uC coding. Forget about it. Try to forget about the malloc and friends at all.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it is STM32 uC - there are no memory segments.

Comment: @P__J__ For the spiTXBuffers im using calloc in the main. The pResult pointer is a different story :) What else would you recommend? I already tried initializing the spiTXBuffers as "normal" arrays in the global space as well.

Comment: Try to avoid any dynamic allocation thinking. There is no one way how to deal with the memory on the systems with very limited resources. Every app is different. Heap is usually very small and you will fragment it in no time. Very similar bug was in the USB HAL driver years ago. So the USB was warkng for about 3 seconds when no host requests and 0 sek when something host started to send requests.

Comment: Calling `calloc()` in an interrupt is clearly not optimal (or even sensical), in most cases. It's just wrong to assume that the heap allocator always will be fast enough to run inside an interrupt, it's not a good idea. But besides that, you also leak the pointer to the heap memory by assigning to `pResult` a few lines down. That's a bug.

Comment: Okay, I will avoid that. But when I disable the interrupt and just access the variable in the while loop I still get the same effect.

Comment: @unwind how would you assign the pointer correctly? Declare it globally?

Comment: @Julian I think you should stop using heap allocations in the interrupt, and pre-allocate all needed buffers. That generally requires making them more or less global, yes.

Comment: In addition, you seem to have to protection against re-entrancy bugs. And you shouldn't use floating point inside an ISR, if at all. This code can't be salvaged, you need to step back from it and start by first studying embedded systems, interrupts, re-entrant code, real-time programming and so on.

Comment: Can you add the code pertaining to the initialization of the DMA? `Disabling the DMA ADC fixes the issue`

Comment: first, try make `spiTxBuffers` variable `volatile`, second, something strange in the interrupt: `pResult` is assigned to `= (uint8_t *) calloc(...)` and this result never used, the variable is reassigned again below: `pResult = spiTxBuffers + ...`. Probably a memory leak. Please clarify what is happening there.

Comment: First you allocate some space by `spiTxBuffers = (uint8_t *) calloc(max_serial*buffer_size, sizeof(uint8_t));`, but then you fill more than that in the loop `for (int i=0; i <= max_serial; i++) {`. But I'm afraid that this is just _another_ error. ;-) If `buffer_size` is constant you could avoid `calloc()` in the ISR. And if `max_serial` is also constant you could avoid `calloc()` in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't call calloc in an interrupt.
2. Make the array `volatile`

Just my 2 cents.